# Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_input_buffer'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to start a script in SQL Server 2014, but it can't find the object in question.

This is the query I am trying to initiate:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_input_buffer(@@SPID, NULL);
```

Error message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Invalid object name 'sys.dm_exec_input_buffer'.

Comment: Some suggested reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3). `a` is for `dm_exec_sessions`, `b` is for `dm_exec_requests`? That is *really* confusing. There is no `a` or `b` in either of those object names.

Comment: @Larnu The kicker is that they're not even in alphabetical order: `a` `b` `c` `f` `d` `e` `g`

Comment: Another bad habit: not specifying the full column list for `INSERT`. If the table schema changes then you will get errors

Comment: Wait, is that not the right order, @Charlieface ? Excuse me, I need to go and check my kid's Alphabet book...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be on at least Service Pack 2. If you're on an earlier service pack, it's time to patch.

- [Here's a link to Service Pack 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4022619/sql-server-2014-service-pack-3-release-information)
- [Here's a link to the most recent update for SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?FamilyID=265b2dc0-b705-4466-bb7b-d2433c4263ab)

Please apply both, in that order.

Comment: The fact that they aren't using SP2 also means that they have multiple security patches that aren't applied, such as those against Spectre and Meltdown; somewhat concerning.